# IJCADのバージョンアップによりGcad.Applicationのオブジェクトが取得できなくなった

Tags: vba, ijcad

VBAでIJCADの操作をするプログラムが、IJCADのアップデート（2018→2019）により
「実行時エラー９１　オブジェクト変数withブロック変数が設定されていません」 と表示されるようになってしまいました。

VBAの参照設定はGcadの2019に修正しています。
操作対象のCADは起動した状態でもエラーが出ます。

```
Dim getTimesec As Double
Dim GcadApp As GcadApplication
Set GcadApp = GetObject(, "Gcad.Application")　　←ここの行でオブジェクトが取得できていない
Set GcadDoc = GcadApp.ActiveDocument
```

オブジェクトが取得できなくなったのは、IJCADのバージョンによるものなのか、コードがおかしいのでしょうか。
VBA初心者なので上記の情報で判断材料が足りるか分かりませんが…よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

IJCAD 2019でGetObjectを使う際はバージョンを指定すると正常にオブジェクトを取得できると思います。

まずは、VBAでIJCADのライブラリを参照していて、VBAで参照しているIJCADが起動しているのを確認してください。

そして

```
GetObject(, "Gcad.Application")
```

で取得するIJCADのバージョンを指定するために

```
GetObject(, "Gcad.Application.19")
```

に書き換えてみてください。

Comment: さっそくIJCADのバージョンを指定するよう書き換えてみたところ、正常に動作するようになりました！ありがとうございました！